# undefined method `each' for #<Comment:0x007f12ef55d0d0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was working through the ruby on rails blogger tutorial on:
 http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments
and i am at the point where I am fixing the show action for the blogger app.

here is my controller:

```
def show
@articles = Article.find(params[:id])
@comment = Comment.new
@comments = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

here is my show view - (which is rendering my comments partial)

```
`<br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <%=render partial: 'comments/form'%>
 <br/>

 <h3>Comments</h3>
 <%= render partial: 'articles/comment'%>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <small><%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %></small>
 `
```

here is my comments partial:

```
 <div>
 <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
 <h4>Comment by:<%=comment.author_name%></h4>
 <p class="comment"><%=comment.body%></p>
 <%end%>
 </div>
```

My problem is that when i am trying to display all the comments from the Comment model
on the show page through the each iterator in the comments partial, I get this error:

```
 undefined method `each' for #<Comment:0x007f12ef55d0d0>
```

I dont see any problems with my instance variables in the show action. and the each method
that I wrote, has the proper syntax. Does anyone know What this error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error basically means that you are expecting an array of comments, but only have a comment. The way you called find will only return one object, not an array. You need to adjust the following line:

`@comments = Comment.find(params[:id])`

If your relationships are set up correctly, you should be able to replace it with something like this:

`@comments = article.comments`